# Get text from any file type using Python

Tags: python, file, text

I have a file which is **not** `.txt` extension, but I can right click and open it using notepad, and it's a readable file.
However, if I try to open the file I cannot retrieve the text, or edit it.
Here's some code to make things clearer:

```
path=r"C:\Users\Alon\Desktop\RUN Low.spe"
f=open(path,'r+')
f.readlines()
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Again, if I try to open this file using Notepad - no problems. I can read and edit the text, but I wanna do it via Python. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: That doesnt sound like a python problem, python doesnt care what the file is

Comment: Is your file empty?

Comment: Can you try `open(path, 'rb')`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: Where does the `[]` come from ?

Comment: Hi guys, 
The file is not empty, and I tried to open it as 'rb', but it didn't work either..
And the [] is from the f.readlines